# Does Nvidia vGPU Software support Docker container?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-docker

Hello Stackoverflow experts!

I have Telsa K40m on the private cluster, and my goal is to check how much performance I can gain by partitioning the GPU into multiple vGPUs and then run them concurrently with Docker containers.

My concern is that I am not sure whether vGPUs support Docker Container or only limited to VMs. 
Would someone help me answer this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Docs say virtual architecture should be chosen as low as possible https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#gpu-compilation and recommends using separate GPUs per docker container https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am asking about the availability of using vGPUs with docker.